# What is the most efficient way to display a sparse dataset as a table in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to display data in a table where there is a many-to-one relationship between my column values (Components) and my rows (Materials). There is a further many-to-one relationship between these column values and the column headers (ComponentTypes). At the moment I have implemented something similar to this in my view:

rows:

```
materials_list = Materials.objects.all()
```

columns:

```
component_type_list = Components.objects.filter(material__in = materials_list).values("component__name")
```

Establishing the values for the row in the order of the column titles:

```
for material in materials:
    component_list = []
    for component_type in component_type_list:
        try:
            component = material.components_set.filter(component__name = component_type['component__name'])[0].weight_pct
        except:
            component = 0
        component_list.append(component)
    material.component_list_for_table = component_list
```

I then pass materials and component_type_list to the template where I have the following:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Guru ID</th>
        <th>Material</br>Code</th>
    {% for component_type in component_type_list %}
        <th>{{ component_type.component__name }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% for material in materials %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ material.GURU_ID }}</th>
        <th>{{ material.MATERIALCODE }}</th>
        {% for component in material.component_list_for_table %}
        <td>{{ component|floatformat }}%</td>     
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Even with just 50 rows (potentially ~100 columns) this operates extremely slowly. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

I have edited the code to simplify it so it may not be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

- use Django Debug Toolbar to check how many queries you've got and how long they take. You mention "this operates extremely slowly" but it's good to have data.
- have you tried to use `prefetch_related` to limit queries?
- I'd use Python code (like you did) to reorganise data in the records if that's too complicated through SQL.

Maybe something like this:

```
materials_list = Materials.objects.prefetch_related('components_set').prefetch_related('components_set__type').all()

for material in material_list:
     component_list = []
     # your logic here - which should run fast thanks to the prefetches.
     material.component_list = component_list
```